# How to go from one gesture recognizer to the another

Tags: ios, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a map drawn with OpenGLES, and I have a pan gesture recognizer that has maximumNumberofTouches set to 1 to pan around the map and a pinch gesture recognizer for zooming. I want to start panning once im done zooming, (one finger is lifted off the screen) but the pan gesture recognizer doesnt kick in until pinchgesturerecognizer is done which is when it detects there are no fingers on the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to allow both gestures to be active via the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    //  The two recognizers using the delegate (scale and rotate) should both be active.
    //
    return YES;
}
```

And keep a BOOL that tracks if the user is zooming, not allowing the code in the pan gesture to execute while that BOOL is YES.  Altering the BOOL value by checking the number of touches in the touchesMoved:withEvent method (or perhaps some other UIGestureRegonizer method).

I think this should work, I do something similar in an app that allows scaling, rotating, and dragging, where dragging is only allowed when the user isn't scaling/rotating.

~Good Luck

Comment: found something similar here: http://www.mindtreatstudios.com/our-projects/ios-gesture-recognizer-tips-tricks/